# To access shared SharedPreference from service in android

Tags: android

I want to access SharedPreference within my background service i'd used `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` but it gives nullpoint Exception

Thanks

Comment: show me your code.....
than i can explain where problem come...

Comment: Yes I don't think many people will be eager to help if you have a track record of never acknowledging it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to use the Context like this:

```
Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
```

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
SharedPreference pref = getSharedPreferences(PrefName, 0);
```

Comment: SharedPreference should be SharedPreferences (missing s). I tried to edit it directly but website doesn't allow editing less than 6 letters.

Answer (score 3):

If you have created **SharedPreferences** like:

```
private static final String PREFS_NAME = "UserData";
private static final String PREFS_VALUE1 = "value1";
```

then use this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
value1 = preferences.getString(PREFS_VALUE1, "default_no");
```

Comment: More better option than this is to create a singleton Preferences class to store and retrieve values from SharedPreferences.